# out of memory and vector of vectors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-structures, vector

I'm implementing a distance matrix that calculates the distance between each point and all the other points and I have 100,000 points, so my matrix size will be 100,000 x 100,000. I implemented that using `vector<vector<double> > dist`. However, for this large data size it give out of memory error. The following is my code and any help will be really appreciated.

```
vector<vector<double> > dist(dat.size()) vector<double>(dat.size()));
size_t p,j;
ptrdiff_t i;
#pragma omp parallel for private(p,j,i) default(shared)
for(p=0;p<dat.size();++p)
{
// #pragma omp parallel for private(j,i) default(shared)
for (j = p + 1; j < dat.size(); ++j)
{
double ecl = 0.0;
for (i = 0; i < c; ++i)
{
ecl += (dat[p][i] - dat[j][i]) * (dat[p][i] - dat[j][i]);
}
ecl = sqrt(ecl);
dist[p][j] = ecl;
dist[j][p] = ecl;
}
}
```

Comment: 10 billion entries of 8 byte each means you need 80GB of memory for this data structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 100000 x 100000 matrix? A quick calculation shows why this is never going to work:

```
100000 x 100000 x 8 (bytes) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) = 74.5 gigabytes...
```

Even if it was possible to allocate this much memory I doubt very much whether this would be an efficient approach for a real problem.

If you're looking to do some kind of geometric processing on large data sets you may be interested in some kind of spatial tree structure: [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [r-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) maybe?

Answer (score 2):

`100,000 * 100,000 = 10,000,000,000 ~= 2^33`

It is easy to see that in 32 bits system - an out of memory is guaranteed for such a large data base, without even calculating the fact that we found number of elements, and not number of bytes used.

Even in 64 bits systems, it is highly unlikely that the OS will allow you to so much memory [also note that you actually need much more memory, also because each element you allocate is much more then a byte.]

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that 100,000 times 100,000 is 10 billion?  If you're storing the distances as 32-bit integers, that would 40 billion bytes, or 37.5 GB.  That is probably more RAM than you have so this will not be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

100,000 x 100,000 x sizeof( double ) = roughly 80GIG (with 8 byte doubles) without the overhead of the vectors.

That's not likely to happen unless you're on a really big machine.
Look at using a database of some sort or one of the C/C++ collection libs that spills large data to disk.

Rogue Wave's SourcePRO class library has a few disk based collection classes but it is not free.